# Как правильно создать объект с полями на основе GET параметров соблюдая типы?

Tags: php, классы

Есть класс с некими свойствами. Их много. Ожидается, что типы будут различные и строковые и целые и булево и т.д.

```
class TestClass {

    /***
     * @var int id .....Описание
     */
    public $nodeId; 
    /***
     * @var string .....Описание
     */
    public $type;
    /***
     * @var bool .....Описание
     */
    public $isComponent = false;

    // Ещё много
    // много
    // других свойств

    public static function createFromRequestParams(string $requestParams): self {
        $testClass  = new TestClass;

        foreach($requestParams as $key => $value)
            $testClass->{$key} = $value;

        $testClass->nodeId = (int)$testClass->nodeId;
        $testClass->type = (string)$testClass->type;        
        $testClass->isComponent = (bool)$testClass->isComponent;

        return $testClass;
    }
}
```

Будем считать, что `$requestParams` - это уже массив ключ => значение параметров из *GET*

Как на основе этих *GET* параметров создать экземпляр этого класса так, чтобы все необходимые типы соблюдались? То есть сейчас, если в цикле перебирать значения, то всё будет строковые.

Пока всё что пришло в голову - вручную все поля конвертировать.

Еще можно рефлексию использовать - но это черезчур.

В *Java* есть специальные утилиты преобразования *Json* в объекты классов. А тут можно так же сделать как-то в автоматизированном режиме?

Comment: get он же строка, и пыхе же тоже безразлично, что это в строке - буля или инта или строка. Вопрос - зачем вам такое преобразование в php?

Comment: Самый примолиненйый вариант: в цикле где заполняете класс делаете проверки типа is_numeric и придаете int если true. Сложность с bool, потому что однозначно понять "true" - это строка или bool должен быть - не возможно, без дополнительного контекста.

Comment: @Kirill не уверен, но мне кажется при строгой типизации php 7.4 , если в свойство засунуть другой тип - будет ошибка.

Comment: @Pavel  всё так. Но, по-первых, автор же не говорил за стрикт тайп, хоть в примере он и есть. По-вторых,  в любом случае ошибок (по крайней мере TypeError, по крайней мере в куске кода из вопроса) не будет. string $requestParams - пришла строка - норм, венрулся self - норм. В теле метода автор типы поприводил - норм (хотя хз зачем). Я так понимаю, что где-то дальше класс оперирует этими свойствами, и там уже указаны типы принимаемых аргументов. Но мы этого не узнаем :) Мне кажется в примере кода всё ок.

Comment: @Kirill "Вопрос - зачем вам такое преобразование в php?" --- ну я использую строгую типизацию, да и вообще типизацию как таковую и хочу её придерживаться. и когда на вход я ожидаю int и подаю например `$testClass->nodeId` чтобы работало корректно, а не попасть в ловушки.

Comment: Думаю, в примере кода в вопросе всё норм.

Comment: @Kirill то есть ручное присваивание в целом кажется приемлемым? Даже если 20 полей будет?) А если не сколько подобных классов будет никак не связанных по контексту, что наследованием и прочими штуками не решить?)

Comment: @Kirill кажется мне нужен гидратор) Короч рефлексия поможет выстроить грамотнее всё, как я полагал)